# Camera Preview error and thumbnail okay in Android

Tags: android, uiimageview, android-camera, android-external-storage

I am using the imageview to keep the captured image in the layout and saved into the storage space. All are behaving well in my code except one. After the image was captured the imageview have the last latest image I captured and in the storage also the thumbnail showing the last captured image.

But when I click the thumb to see the preview, it was always showing there as the first image. While saving the image I kept same name for all the time. How to fix this to view the preview of latest saved image. I don't want to change the name.

```
     @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==R.id.cust_save)
        saveCustomerData();
    if(v.getId()==R.id.cust_photo)
        mobile11=mobile1.getText().toString();
        captureImage();
}
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);     
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);   
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
private void saveCustomerData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
/**
 * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
 * app
 */
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
    // changes
    outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // get the file url
    fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
}

/**
 * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Display image from a path to ImageView
 */
private void previewCapturedImage() {
    try {
        //cam_img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // bimatp factory
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
        // images
        options.inSampleSize = 8;

        final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(),
                options);
        Log.e("File Storage is : ",fileUri.getPath());

        cam_img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * ------------ Helper Methods ---------------------- 
 * */

/**
 * Creating file uri to store image/video
 */
public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
}

/**
 * returning image / video
 */
private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

    // External sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                    + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    //String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            //Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() +File.separator + mobile11 +".jpg");
    } 
    else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a Kitkat or Lolipop based device  ??

Comment: ICS I am using to test the app

Comment: Can you elaborate the scenario. I'm actually getting confused about what you are trying to achieve and what you are doing. :)

Comment: Look at this project.Custom camera https://github.com/devcelebi/Kut-Camera

Comment: I have the imageview to keep the captured image and the same image is stored in SD. When I took photos for second time the imageview got updated and the thumbnail for that image is also updated, but not the preview of that image(click the thumb on sd it was showing the 1st image)

Comment: @devcelebi That github example is not saving the image in that path.

Comment: My app saving the image correctly when I change the name. Every time I need to change the name to save the image. But my need is not like that. I need to maintain the same name always.